# using 1 variables in different constructor in java

Tags: java, variables, constructor

```
@Override
public void onIrEvent(IREvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


ardrone.addAttitudeUpdateListener(new AttitudeListener() {
        @Override
        public void attitudeUpdated(float pitch, float roll, float yaw, int altitude) {
        System.out.println("altitude : " + altitude);
        }
    });
```

i want to take the variables altitude from the second constructor and use it in the first constructor. I tried to use it directly and it didnt work. I also tried to construct the 2nd constructor inside the 1st one, but also didn't work. any idea?

thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new class that implements `AttitudeListener`. Have a instance variable `altitude` with setter and getter method for the `altitude` and use it accordingly in your first and second constructor.

Example : in AttitudeListenerImpl.java

```
class AttitudeListenerImpl implements AttitudeListener
{
    private int altitude;
    public void setAltitude(int altitude)
    {
        this.altitude = altitude;
    }
    public int getAltitude()
    {
        return this.altitude;
    }
    @Override
    public void attitudeUpdated(float pitch, float roll, float yaw, int altitude) 
    {
        setAltitude(altitude);
        System.out.println("altitude : " + altitude);
    }
}
```

Usage in your other code:

```
AttitudeListener alti = new AttitudeListenerImpl();
alti.attitudeUpdated(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1);
ardrone.addAttitudeUpdateListener(alti);

@Override
public void onIrEvent(IREvent e) 
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //to get the altitude:
         System.out.println("altitude : " + alti.getAltitude()); 

}
```

Comment: where should i put this? main constructor?
AttitudeListener alti = new AttitudeListenerImpl();
alti.attitudeUpdated(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1);
ardrone.addAttitudeUpdateListener(alti);

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any constructor here. Are you talking about `AttitudeListener`? In this case, you would need to create a class implementing this interface.

What you could do then is constructor chaining, like for example:

```
public class MyAttitudeListener implements AttitudeListener
{
    public MyAttitudeListener()
    {
        this(3); // this is like new MyAttitudeListener(3);
    }
    public MyAttitudeListener(int altitude)
    {
        // do some work
    }        
}
```

Could you explain further what goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: trying to control a quadcopter using wiimote.
i need that altitude variables for the controls.